# Android Vulkan instance->createDebugUtilsMessengerEXT call causes art_sigsegv_fault

Tags: android, vulkan

It is working in other platforms but for android this won't for some reason.

The vulkan layers libraries are correctly loaded and VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation layer is on.

[image]

Anyone has any clue?

**Edit 1:**

I cannot link images on comments so I edited this for a first time.
This is the value of the function pointer vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT:
[image]

Comment: Emulator or real device? If real device, which one (which vendor?). I suspect vendor-specific issues coming your way

Comment: Thanks for answering @Shark. It is failing on both hardware and emulator!.

Comment: A sigsegv is often caused by passing uninitialized data to a Vulkan function call. But before checking that: are you properly loading the function pointer to `vkcreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT` and is the `VK_EXT_debug_utils` extension enabled?

Comment: Thanks for answer @SaschaWillems!. I have enabled VK_EXT_DEBUG_UTILS_EXTENSION_NAME and VK_EXT_DEBUG_REPORT_EXTENSION_NAME.
Also have linked this way:
vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT = reinterpret_cast<PFN_vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT>(vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT"));
The function pointer passes from nullptr to an address value that feels to be the right one. I have posted the image in the Edit 1.

Comment: Worth mention that I got tons of errors and had to build a wrapper file to link everything in an Initialization step.
This is currently my header inclusion:

#include "vulkan-wrapper.hpp" // Do not confuse with vulkan_wrapper.h
#undef VK_NO_PROTOTYPES
#include <vulkan/vulkan.hpp>

Comment: @SaschaWillems you were right. I was trying to enable VK_EXT_debug_utils but it seems there is no such extension. Is there anything I can do regarding it?.